# Hibernate @CollectionOfElements and @Parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, parent-child

I've done the following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NWS_NEWS")
public class News implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5246618151933389186L;

    private String id;
    private List<Picture> pictures;

    + OTHER fields / getters / setters, no matter

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "juuid")
    @Column(length = 36)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }


    @CollectionOfElements
    @JoinTable(name = "NWS_PICTURES",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="NEWS_ID"))
    @CollectionId(
            columns= @Column(name="PICTURE_ID"),
            type=@Type(type="long"),
            generator="sequence")
    public List<Picture> getPictures() {
        return pictures;
    }

    public void setPictures(List<Picture> pictures) {
        this.pictures = pictures;
    }



}
```

And my picture is:

```
@Embeddable
public class Picture implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1397366206984323622L;

    private News news;

    private String path;

    private ImageSize imageSize;


    @Parent
    public News getNews() {
        return this.news;
    }

    @Column(name = "path", nullable=false)
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "size", nullable=false)
    public ImageSize getImageSize() {
        return imageSize;
    }


    public void setImageSize(ImageSize imageSize) {
        this.imageSize = imageSize;
    }
    public void setNews(News news) {
        this.news = news;
    }
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }


}
```

And my dao test is:

```
@Test
public void testAddPicturesToNews() {

    News newsToSave = new News();
    // Create big picture
    Picture pBig = new Picture();
    pBig.setImageSize(ImageSize.BIG);
    pBig.setPath("/tmp/blabla_big.jpg");
    // Create medium picture
    Picture pMedium = new Picture();
    pMedium.setImageSize(ImageSize.MEDIUM);
    pMedium.setPath("/tmp/blabla_med.jpg");
    // Set the pictures in the news
    List<Picture> picturesList = new ArrayList<Picture>();
    picturesList.add(pBig);
    picturesList.add(pMedium);
    newsToSave.setPictures(picturesList);
    // Save the news
    this.newsDAO.saveOrUpdate(newsToSave);
    String newsId = newsToSave.getId();
    News newsLoaded = this.newsDAO.findById(newsId);
    List<Picture> picturesLoaded = newsLoaded.getPictures();
    for ( Picture pictureLoaded : picturesLoaded ) {
        System.out.println(pictureLoaded.getPath());
        System.out.println(pictureLoaded.getImageSize());
        System.out.println(pictureLoaded.getNews());
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

}
```

But the output is:

```
/tmp/blabla_big.jpg
BIG
null


/tmp/blabla_med.jpg
MEDIUM
null
```

Actually i don't understand why getNews() returns null in the child entity entity, while it has the "@Parent" annotation. Am i doing something wrong?

Anyway the concept of getting the parent in a child entity seems a bit strange for me since what would happen if i do something like that:

```
News news1 = new News();
News news2 = new News();
List<Picture> picList = new ArrayList<Picture>();
Picture picture1 = new Picture();
picturesList.add(picture1);
picture1.setNews(news2);
news1.setPictures(picList);
this.newsDAO.saveOrUpdate(news1);
this.newsDAO.saveOrUpdate(news2);
```

What would happen since the same picture will be in news1 list, but also its parent was set to news2???

I think i'll do without that parent, i don't need that so much but it's just curiosity...
Thanks

Btw i'd like to have only one picture of each size for a news -> there can't be 2 small pictures for the same news.
So is it possible to add a unique constraint on {news_id , imageSize} in my embedded entity? I don't see how to do that since no id field is declared in my Picture embeddable entity

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the @Parent annotation for an @Embeddable, but for "real" relationships it's always recommended to do something like this:

```
// News class
public void setPictures(List<Picture> pictures) {
  this.pictures = pictures;
  for (Picture picture : pictures) {
    picture.setNews(this);
  }
}

public void addPicture(Picture picture) {
  this.pictures.add(picture);
  picture.setNews(this);
}
```

Remember that OOP, as opposed to the relational model, has only the notion of a "one-way" navigation, and that you should build the "two-way" by yourself. Encapsulating this behavior in the setter makes this transparent to your consumers. So, I'm not sure why your @Parent is not working, but I would try to do the opposite:

```
// what you have:
newsToSave.setPictures(picturesList);

// what I'd try:
pMedium.setNews(newsToSave);
```

> What would happen since the same picture will be in news1 list, but also its parent was set to news2???

Well, an @Embeddable is an object which is "embedded" into another, meaning that it belongs only to that other object (parent). As such, it should contain only one parent. If you change the parent, it'll belong only to this new parent. If you need an object (`Picture`) to have a relationship with other objects (`News`), you'll need a @ManyToMany (if the other object, `News`, may also be linked to several `Picture`)